# How to wrangle overlapping dates in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a staff rota which is automatically produced by a data download. Every now and again, the start and finish dates wont be entirely correct. For example someone might be on the rota between 01/04/2019 until 10/04/2019 but then output will break this date period up as two rows eg 01/04/2019 until 05/04/2019 and 05/04/2019 until 10/04/2019. This is shown in the dataframe StaffRota with the desired output shown in StaffRota2.

```
#create some data - shows the raw data from the download
StaffRota<-data.frame(Name=c("Ian", "Ian", "Ian", "Fred","Fred","Mark","Alex","Ian","Fred","Ian","Fred","Fred"),
                      RotaStart=c("2019-04-01","2019-04-03", "2019-04-06","2019-04-02","2019-04-05","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-07-01","2019-08-01","2019-04-12","2019-09-02","2019-09-06"),
                      RotaFinish=c("2019-04-03", "2019-04-06", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-05", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-05","2019-07-31","2019-08-30","2019-04-20","2019-09-04","2019-09-08"))
StaffRota$RotaStart<-as.Date(StaffRota$RotaStart, "%Y-%m-%d")
StaffRota$RotaFinish<-as.Date(StaffRota$RotaFinish, "%Y-%m-%d")

#how the dataframe should look
StaffRota2<-data.frame(Name=c("Ian", "Fred","Mark","Alex","Ian","Fred","Ian","Fred","Fred"),
                       RotaStart=c("2019-04-01","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-04-02","2019-07-01","2019-08-01","2019-04-12","2019-09-02","2019-09-06"),
                       RotaFinish=c("2019-04-10","2019-04-10", "2019-04-10", "2019-04-05","2019-07-31","2019-08-30","2019-04-20","2019-09-04","2019-09-08"))
```

I want to transform the data so that the columns where the dates are split up as shown in StaffRota are consolidated into one continuous start and end date as shown in StaffRota2.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` you could group by month:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

StaffRota %>%
    mutate(mnth = month(RotaFinish)) %>%
    group_by(Name, mnth) %>%
    slice(which.max(as.Date(RotaFinish, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-mnth)  

# Name  RotaStart  RotaFinish
# <fct> <date>     <date>    
#1 Alex  2019-04-02 2019-04-05
#2 Fred  2019-04-05 2019-04-10
#3 Fred  2019-08-01 2019-08-30
#4 Ian   2019-04-06 2019-04-10
#5 Ian   2019-07-01 2019-07-31
#6 Mark  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
```

## Edit

You can also group by week using `isoweek`

```
StaffRota %>%
    mutate(wk = isoweek(RotaStart)) %>%
    group_by(Name, wk) %>%
    slice(which.max(as.Date(RotaFinish, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-wk)

#  Name  RotaStart  RotaFinish
#  <fct> <date>     <date>    
#1 Alex  2019-04-02 2019-04-05
#2 Fred  2019-04-05 2019-04-10
#3 Fred  2019-08-01 2019-08-30
#4 Ian   2019-04-06 2019-04-10
#5 Ian   2019-04-12 2019-04-20
#6 Ian   2019-07-01 2019-07-31
#7 Mark  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
```

## Edit 2

another option based on your edit is to create an index to group the data rather than relying on week/month :

```
StaffRota %>%
    arrange(Name, RotaStart) %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(RotaStart)) > cummax(as.numeric(RotaFinish)))[-n()])) %>%
    group_by(Name, indx) %>%
    summarise(RotaStart = first(RotaStart), RotaFinish = last(RotaFinish)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-indx)

#  Name  RotaStart  RotaFinish
#  <fct> <date>     <date>    
#1 Alex  2019-04-02 2019-04-05
#2 Fred  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
#3 Fred  2019-08-01 2019-08-30
#4 Fred  2019-09-02 2019-09-04
#5 Fred  2019-09-06 2019-09-08
#6 Ian   2019-04-01 2019-04-10
#7 Ian   2019-04-12 2019-04-20
#8 Ian   2019-07-01 2019-07-31
#9 Mark  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
```

Comment: The problem is that if Ian for example did another shift in April between 2019-04-12 and 2019-04-20 then both of the April shifts (2019-04-01 to 2019-04-10 and 2019-04-12 to 2019-04-20) wouldn't show in the table as 2 separate rows. I will add these dates into my code (I hadn't initially anticipated that scenario)

Comment: It solves that issue but then if you had 2 shifts start in the same week eg 2019-09-02 to 04-09-2019 and 2019-09-06 to 2019-09-08 then only the last one would show in the table. I have updated my code to also include that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could utilize a `lead()`/`lag()` combo as well as some of the newer `library(tidyr)` pivoting functions.

Simply put, we pivot long, arrange, look for duplicate dates, filter them out, then duplicate Rota types and filter them out. A wide pivot gives us the desired output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

StaffRota <-
  tribble(
    ~Name,  ~RotaStart,   ~RotaFinish,
    "Ian",  "2019-04-01", "2019-04-03",
    "Ian",  "2019-04-03", "2019-04-06",
    "Ian",  "2019-04-06", "2019-04-10",
    "Fred", "2019-04-02", "2019-04-05",
    "Fred", "2019-04-05", "2019-04-10",
    "Mark", "2019-04-02", "2019-04-10",
    "Alex", "2019-04-02", "2019-04-05",
    "Ian",  "2019-07-01", "2019-07-31",
    "Fred", "2019-08-01", "2019-08-30",
    "Ian",  "2019-04-12", "2019-04-20",
    "Fred", "2019-09-02", "2019-09-04",
    "Fred", "2019-09-06", "2019-09-08")

StaffRota %>%
  pivot_longer(RotaStart:RotaFinish,
               names_to = "Rota",
               values_to = "Date") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Name, Date) %>% 
  filter(Date != lag(Date, default = +Inf)) %>%
  filter(Rota != lead(Rota, default = -Inf)) %>% 
  group_by(Name, Rota) %>%
  mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(Name, n),
    names_from = Rota,
    values_from = Date
  ) %>% 
  select(-n)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   Name [4]
#>   Name  RotaStart  RotaFinish
#>   <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 Alex  2019-04-02 2019-04-05
#> 2 Fred  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
#> 3 Fred  2019-08-01 2019-08-30
#> 4 Fred  2019-09-02 2019-09-04
#> 5 Fred  2019-09-06 2019-09-08
#> 6 Ian   2019-04-01 2019-04-10
#> 7 Ian   2019-04-12 2019-04-20
#> 8 Ian   2019-07-01 2019-07-31
#> 9 Mark  2019-04-02 2019-04-10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>